# How can I verify that TransPort is working correctly?

Tags: transparent-proxy

I have a Tor router set up as docker image, but there's an issue (as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48602056/what-are-the-correct-iptables-rules-to-use-a-tor-proxy-as-network-gateway).

Now I would like to debug the Tor side - the **TransPort** specifically.

Currently, when running `telnet localhost 9040` it immediately terminates with "Connection closed by foreign host". I suspect that's not the intended result (?)

**How can I best further investigate/debug?**

Comment: That sounds like expected functionality. TransPort isn't something you connect directly to, it's expecting `-j REDIRECT`ed packets.

Comment: Hmm ... any idea on the referenced issue then (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48602056/what-are-the-correct-iptables-rules-to-use-a-tor-proxy-as-network-gateway)? iptables says it's actually `-j REDIRECT`'ing

Comment: I wonder if it's related to *how* Docker moves data from the container to the outside world through another process. I'll give this a test and I'll get back to you on it, but my guess is that the information of the original destination is being lost between the kernel and Tor through `docker-proxy`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is likely `docker-proxy`. I used a small python script to illustrate this, having set up `-j REDIRECT` for a user and tested it inside and outside of `docker`.

The script itself looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import socket
from struct import unpack
if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = socket.socket()
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    s.bind(('0.0.0.0',9040))
    s.listen(1)
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    orig = conn.getsockopt(socket.SOL_IP, 80, 16) # 80 is socket.SO_ORIGINAL_DST but python doesn't define it.
    port, ip = unpack("!2xH4s8x", orig)
    print('{}:{}'.format(socket.inet_ntoa(ip), port))
```

Then we load up our `docker`ised python script, with 9040 exposed and try to `curl https://check.torproject.org` from our transparently proxied user.

```
# docker run -it --rm --name origdest -p "9040:9040" -v "$PWD":/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp python:3 python origdest.py
172.17.0.2:9040
```

We see that the `docker`ised script believes the original destination is the internal container IP address, *not* the intended destination. Compare this to the non-`docker`ised script

```
# python3 origdest.py 
138.201.14.212:443
```

Transparent proxying works by Tor querying the original destination through `getsockopt`. It gets it from the conntrack table in the kernel, but because `docker-proxy` is forwarding on behalf of the user to the Tor running inside of the container when it tries to look up the original destination it sees it's own `TransProxy` port and the connection fails.

Comment: I'm failing to understand fully yet. So conntrack basically says "check.torproject.org is 172.17.0.2" and thus the container tries to talk to that IP instead of the correct one (138...)?

Any way to tackle the situation regardless?

Comment: No, when the `REDIRECT` is applied the original destination is still kept in the kernel's conntrack table. When Tor receives a connection to it's TransPort it can use `getsockopt()` to lookup the original destination (not Tor's Transport). Because the container gets it's traffic via `docker-proxy` it takes in a connection from outside of the container, and makes a connection inside of the container and bridges the two. Tor gets the connection from `docker-proxy` and so can't lookup the original destination because it's not the same connection, it's a new one `docker-proxy` made.

Comment: Got it. So, in theory, if, instead of bridged networking, I'd go for the **macvlan** or, preferably, the **overlay** driver, the issue should be avoidable? (https://docs.docker.com/network/overlay/)

Comment: I don't know enough about Docker internals to answer definitively but I think if both host and container share the same network interface so they both see the same connection, then it should work.

Comment: According to some research and further tests, `docker-proxy` is not active at all. The issue is most likely caused elsewhere.

Comment: What happens if you run my script in the same situation?

Comment: With your script, `docker-proxy` is indeed fired up and I get **FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory** on line 10 (`orig = ...`) once I execute the `curl` command on the host.

Also, if I *do* run the tor-router image with `-p "9040:9040"`, `docker-proxy` does pop up in the process table, but the behaviour doesn't change at all (curl still hanging).

Important to mention that `curl --proxy socks5h://${TOR_ROUTER_IP}:9050 https://check.torproject.org/api/ip` **does** work regardless of using any `-p` or not - **without** `docker-proxy` - meaning 9050 is available on host.

Comment: SOCKS would work, TransPort works on an entirely different principle. If you could add a mock-up of your Dockerfile I can take another look and see if I can find anything, though.

Comment: That's the container source: https://github.com/flungo-docker/tor-router (Dockerfile at https://github.com/flungo-docker/tor-router/blob/master/src/Dockerfile)